# Function overloading trick - compiler cannot choose which function to call

Tags: rust

Rust has no function overloading: you cannot define multiple functions with the same name but with different arguments.

However, I discovered the following trick which makes it look like there is function overloading. Notice how in `main()` I can call `example.apply(...)` with different types:

```
struct Example;

trait Apply<T, R> {
    fn apply(&self, value: T) -> R;
}

impl Apply<i32, i32> for Example {
    fn apply(&self, value: i32) -> i32 {
        value * 2
    }
}

impl Apply<&str, String> for Example {
    fn apply(&self, value: &str) -> String {
        format!("Hello, {}", value)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let example = Example;

    // Looks like function overloading!
    let one = example.apply(12);
    let two = example.apply("World");

    println!("{}", one);
    println!("{}", two);
}
```

Now I would like to make two different versions of the `Apply` trait: one for values which are `Copy` and one for values which are not `Copy`:

```
struct Example;

struct NotCopy(i32);

// For types which are Copy
trait ApplyCopy<T: Copy, R> {
    fn apply(&self, value: T) -> R;
}

// For types which are not Copy
trait ApplyRef<T, R> {
    fn apply(&self, value: &T) -> R;
}

impl ApplyCopy<i32, i32> for Example {
    fn apply(&self, value: i32) -> i32 {
        value * 2
    }
}

impl ApplyRef<NotCopy, String> for Example {
    fn apply(&self, value: &NotCopy) -> String {
        format!("NotCopy({})", value.0)
    }
}
```

However, when I try to use this I get errors:

```
fn main() {
    let example = Example;

    let one = example.apply(12);            // Error: multiple `apply` found
    let two = example.apply(&NotCopy(34));  // Error: multiple `apply` found

    println!("{}", one);
    println!("{}", two);
}
```

One of the error messages:

```
error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope
  --> src/main.rs:30:23
   |
30 |     let one = example.apply(12);            // Error: multiple `apply` found
   |                       ^^^^^ multiple `apply` found
   |
note: candidate #1 is defined in an impl of the trait `ApplyCopy` for the type `Example`
  --> src/main.rs:16:5
   |
16 |     fn apply(&self, value: i32) -> i32 {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: candidate #2 is defined in an impl of the trait `ApplyRef` for the type `Example`
  --> src/main.rs:22:5
   |
22 |     fn apply(&self, value: &NotCopy) -> String {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: disambiguate the associated function for candidate #1
   |
30 |     let one = ApplyCopy::apply(&example, 12);            // Error: multiple `apply` found
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: disambiguate the associated function for candidate #2
   |
30 |     let one = ApplyRef::apply(&example, 12);            // Error: multiple `apply` found
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The compiler complains that it does not know which `apply` function to call. I expected it to be able to make a choice: an `i32` is not a reference and is `Copy`, so the `apply` of trait `ApplyCopy` is the only one that can be called, and `&NotCopy(34)` is a reference and since `NotCopy` is not `Copy`, only the `apply` of `ApplyRef` can be called.

Is this a limitation of the Rust compiler or am I missing something?

Comment: Experience suggests that you probably want `R` to be an output type, not an input type. [Here's one way to interpret your requirements.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0ef3e2075c4f086681823d75751b3928)

Comment: @trentcl Thanks, that works for what I want to use it for! Can you make it an answer below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a limitation of the Rust compiler or am I missing something?

While there is compiler magic & special casing around them, at a fundamental level *a reference is still a proper type*, so any `T` could be an `&Q` under the covers, and reference types can implement traits.

While `NotCopy` is not Copy, [`&NotCopy` is `Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.reference.html#impl-Copy). So `&NotCopy` matches both cases.

Comment: Aha, I see. But it doesn't explain why the compiler also thinks there are two candidates for `example.apply(12)`. Because an `i32` can't match `ApplyRef.apply()`.

Comment: Right. The issue there would be that it's not a single "namespace". There's a global namespace with all the traits, and then there's a namespace per trait for the trait's implementations. Here what it does is try to find a suitable `apply`, but it only looks at the subject, so it tries to find a `Example::apply` before it even wonders about dispatching within the trait. And it finds two possible candidates (since both traits are implemented for Example) at which point it stops and tells you to disambiguate.

Comment: You can see this clearly by simplifying the entire thing: change ApplyRef to take a `value: bool` and return nothing, impl a trivial impl, change ApplyCopy to take a hard-coded u8 and return nothing, add a trival impl. Change your call to `example.copy` to take something unrelated like a String or an `()`, try to compile, and it doesn't fail to compile because it doesn't find any match (despite there not being any), [it still fails because it doesn't know where to start looking](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=88d9c9f831ba7336ddba00206daeffbb).

Comment: Thanks for looking into it @Masklinn. trentcl's comment made me realize I can do what I want much simpler: just have one `Apply<T>` trait with an output type, for `Copy` types implement it as `Apply<Thing>` and for non-`Copy` types implement it as `Apply<&Thing>` (with the desired output types).